# context.detach - for garbage collection

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

My application uses one context instance which exists for the lifetime of the application.  I use Entity Framework to read and write all data to the database.  After I add objects, I want them to be cleaned up by the garbage collector so that they don't persist in memory.  I've tried the following:

```
    While context.BatchProgresses.Count > 0
        context.Detach(context.BatchProgresses.First())
    End While
```

but this is runs into an infinite loop. Shouldn't `Context.Detach()` remove items from `Context.BatchProgresses`?

Comment: Singleton contexts are a *really bad idea* and will only end in misery. A context is a unit of work. Your unit of work is not "the whole lifetime of my app."

Comment: I appreciate the advice.  I did in the end break the task up into multiple contexts.  I avoided this strategy initially because I was worried about the performance implications of creating and destroying contexts within a timer loop, but it turns out there is little to no performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in such cases, if you don't want to re-query the database, but work with entities attached to the context, you can use the ObjectStateManager:

```
var attachedEntities = context.
                       ObjectStateManager.
                       GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | 
                                             EntityState.Deleted |
                                             EntityState.Modified | 
                                             EntityState.Unchanged).
                       Where(ent => ent.Entity is BatchProgress).
                       Select(ent => ent.Entity as BatchProgress).
                       ToList();

foreach (var attachedEntity in attachedEntities)
{
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(attachedEntity, EntityState.Detached);
}
```

Setting the ObjectState to EntityState.Detached removes the entity from the collection. You can check by fetching attachedEntities again in the end - there will be none.

Answer (score 0):

It is only idea, but possible callingn of BatchProgress.First() causes database reading. Ensure (by logger or SQL profiler) no SQL activity is performed due that call.

Also you may try following code (C#)

```
var list = context.BatchProgress.ToList();
foreach(var item in list)
    context.Detach(item);
```

Comment: Unfortunately context.BatchProgresses.ToList() will also cause a db query.